# Apache HttpClient 4.3.3 with SSL

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I have the following code:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpEntity resEntity = null;

    String endpointUrl = "https://test_demodata.domain.com/test_demodata/upload";

try {
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(endpointUrl);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    throw new DocumentUploadException("Can't create temp file", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new DocumentUploadException("Can't create temp file", e);
} finally {
    if (resEntity != null) {
        try {
            EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DocumentUploadException(
                    "Can't close file upload connection", e);
        }
    }

    if (httpClient != null) {
        try {
            httpClient.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DocumentUploadException(
                    "Can't close file upload connection", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting **404 not found** with following message:

**The requested URL /test_demodata:443/ was not found on this server**

So for some reason HttpClient is trying to add port number to the folder.

I tried to add SSL support but got overwhelmed with amount of depreciated code and couldn't find working solution for new versions.

How can I make HttpClient handle https URLs?

**EDIT:** When I change `endpointUrl` to one that doesn't exist then the error message is different:
**/test_demodata/upload1 was not found on this server**
So, for some reason, the server in question understands that requested folder exists but adds some kind if redirect to **/test_demodata:443/** which generates this error.
This URL works great in IE, FF & Chrome.

Comment: Mostly likely a problem in constructing `httpPost`, or possibly `endpointUrl`.  You might want to add that code to your question.

Comment: `endpointUrl` is just a `String` passed through setter to this class.

Comment: `httpPost` - sorry about this. It's actually `httpGet` constructed above, just made a mistake editing code for the question. I have to write `Post` with files but want to have `Get` working first.